# i have several questions about python scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make python script that's takes data from bscscan.com and show me in terminal.

Idea: when i will type contract address of token i want to get details of this contract address and code will be below.

my first question is how to get correct data for `mcapa` ? `mcapa` showing wrong information like
this $121,048, and not like this $121,048,400.00

second question is `totalbox` showing "121,000,000 BUSD (CSupply: 95,562,821.092145)" and its correct but i want to get only "121,000,000 BUSD"

I don't get it how to make that :/ i tried strip and split but im not getting info which i want

thanks in advnace

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#print holders
cotractpage = requests.get("https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56")
soupa = BeautifulSoup(cotractpage.content, 'html.parser')
tokenholders = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders').get_text()
tokenholdersa = "Holders: " + ((((tokenholders.strip()).strip("Holders:")).strip()).strip(" a ")).strip()
print(tokenholdersa)

#print decimal
decimal = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trDecimals').get_text()
decimala = "Decimal: " + ((((decimal.strip()).strip("Decimals:")).strip()).strip()).strip()
print(decimala)

#print website
website = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_officialsite_1').get_text()
websitea = "Website: " + ((((website.strip()).strip(" Official Site:")).strip()).strip()).strip()
print(websitea)

#print name
website = soupa.find('span', class_='text-secondary small').get_text()
tokename = "Name: " + website
print(tokename)

#printprice
price = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken')
pricebox = price.find('span', class_='d-block').get_text()
print("Price: " + (pricebox).strip())

#print marketcap
mcap = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken').get_text()
mcapa = ((((mcap.strip()).strip("Price")).strip(pricebox)).strip("Market Cap")).strip()
print("Market Cap: " + mcapa)

#print totalsupply
totalbox = soupa.find('div', class_='col-md-8').get_text()
print("Total Supply: " + totalbox)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is almost correct, just minor adjustments:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#print holders
cotractpage = requests.get("https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56")
soupa = BeautifulSoup(cotractpage.content, 'html.parser')
tokenholders = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders').get_text()
tokenholdersa = "Holders: " + ((((tokenholders.strip()).strip("Holders:")).strip()).strip(" a ")).strip()
print(tokenholdersa)

#print decimal
decimal = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trDecimals').get_text()
decimala = "Decimal: " + ((((decimal.strip()).strip("Decimals:")).strip()).strip()).strip()
print(decimala)

#print website
website = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_officialsite_1').get_text()
websitea = "Website: " + ((((website.strip()).strip(" Official Site:")).strip()).strip()).strip()
print(websitea)

#print name
website = soupa.find('span', class_='text-secondary small').get_text()
tokename = "Name: " + website
print(tokename)

#printprice
price = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken')
pricebox = price.find('span', class_='d-block').get_text()
print("Price: " + (pricebox).strip())

#print marketcap
mcapa = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken').get_text()
print("Market Cap: " + re.search(r'Market Cap.*?([$\d,.]+)', mcapa, flags=re.S).group(1))   # <--- we want only amount after "Market Cap"

#print totalsupply
totalbox = soupa.find('div', class_='col-md-8').get_text().split('(')[0].strip()   # <--- we want only first part of the string
print("Total Supply: " + totalbox)
```

Prints:

```
Holders: 8,040
Decimal: 18
Website: https://www.paxos.com/busd/
Name: Binance-Peg BUSD Token
Price: $1.0004 @ 0.032597 BNB (+0.02%)
Market Cap: $121,048,400.00
Total Supply: 121,000,000 BUSD
```

---

Or if you don't want to use regex for `mcap`:

```
#print marketcap
mcapa = soupa.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken').find(id='pricebutton').get_text(strip=True)
print("Market Cap: " + mcapa)
```